# how do i get the first ID when user click on the first row in c# windowsform application

Tags: c#, .net, events, datagridview

This is the windows application:

[image]

so the thing is i want to get the  id when user click the first row and then it goes on with all the rows but what is happening on there is the row is default selected  when i select the first row i don't get the value but when i select the second row i get the first row value and it goes on, selecting 3rd row gives me 2nd row value but i don't want that i need the exact value.

Comment: You should post your code snippet. I assume you subscribe incorrect event.

Comment: show your code. You might just be using wrong index.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id_column_value = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

//selectedRows[0]  0 for the first select if you have multi rows selected.
//cell 0  for the first column which index at datagridview = 0 (id).
```